# Why does GCS say there are no outputs found in GCS-backend?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to understand why my `data` from my `gcs backend` is saying it does not have any outputs.

I have a module called DB which creates a postgres database.

I have a file called outputs.tf, where I have

```
terraform {
  backend "gcs" {
    bucket  = "projectgun-terraform-state"
    prefix  = "db-workspaces"
  }
}
```

I am using a workspace i called `a1`

I run terraform apply and viola, it worked, I created a DB.

Furthermore, when i go into GCS, I can find my bucket, and find my key.  MY workspace name is a1, I have the prefix "db-workspaces", so my remote state is saved in #{my-bucket}/db-workspaces/a1.tfstate.

When I go to that key in my bucket I see a bunch of JSON that looks like this
[image]

If i go into my `db` module, and do `terraform state pull` it looks just like that also. Everything checks out.

But when I go to my other module, I try to access the outputs from GCS, and I can't.

I am using module a1.

```
data "terraform_remote_state" "db" {
  backend = "gcs"

  config = {
    bucket = "projectgun-terraform-state"
    prefix    = "db-workspaces"
  }
}
```

When i try to access this data via outputs, I see

```
 79:   db_user                     = data.terraform_remote_state.db.outputs.user
│     ├────────────────
│     │ data.terraform_remote_state.db.outputs is object with no attributes
│ 
│ This object does not have an attribute named "user".
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there a better way to debug my issue? How could I be sure what key terraform is looking at when it's attempting to pull the data?

Specifically
`data.terraform_remote_state.db.outputs is object with no attributes`

Can i debug `data.terraform_remote_state` ? How can i inspect what's going on here? There are very clearly outputs when i look at the remote state, so I feel like it's grabbing the wrong key, but don't know where to look.

Answer (score 1):

I found a github issue that summarizes the issue I was having and a solution.

https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/24935

```
data "terraform_remote_state" "network" {
  backend   = "gcs"
  workspace = terraform.workspace
  config  = {
    bucket  = "tf-state"
    prefix  = "base-layer/network/"
  }
}
```

This does not seem to be a documented fix. Thank you to @HebertCL for the answer!